# How to do a groupby of a Ray dataset using two keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, distributed, ray

Let’s say I want to groupby A and B and calc the sum of Sales? How should I go about it?

```
import pandas as pd
import ray
ray.init()

rdf = ray.data.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,1,4],'Sales':[20,30,40]})
```

I did try doing rdf.groupby([‘A’,‘B’]) but it gives me an error stating the key column must not be a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported yet, but it's planned to add: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/25732

The workaround is adding a new column to the dataset, say "C", which combines "A" and "B" in the way you want, and then groupby column "C".